# Personal investment portfolio set up as business

Tags: india, business

I have an investment portfolio in the USA, but I am now in India. To save on taxes on capital gains in India on this portfolio, would it help to set up trading in this portfolio as a business? What are the pros and cons of setting up a business for this purpose versus continuing to trade as an individual investor?

Also, is there any time limit on bringing the money in this portfolio to India without tax consequences if I have been paying taxes in India on the capital gains regularly? Can I continue to hold this portfolio indefinitely in the USA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue to hold the portfolio as resident Indian. You have to pay taxes as applicable. There isn't much benefit holding this as a company, there will be more paper work and potentially more taxes, it depends on the size of investment. A CA can calculate the benefits and advise you.